# Javascript regex date extraction and grouping issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these text rows for these lines

```
Il Messaggero Roma 22 settembre 2023
Il Messaggero Roma 21 settembre 2023
Il Messaggero 22 settembre 2023
Il Messaggero 21 settembre 2023
Il Messaggero Roma 21 agosto 2023
Il Messaggero Roma 20 agosto 2023
Le Grandi Glorie del Rock – 15 febbraio 2023
Corriere della Sera Sette 26 agosto 2023
```

and I'm trying to group them like this and with these names

```
Il Messaggero Roma [settembre 2023]
Il Messaggero Roma [agosto 2023]
Il Messaggero [settembre 2023]
Le Grandi Glorie del Rock - [febbraio 2023]
Corriere della Sera Sette [agosto 2023]
```

Instead the rows are incorrectly grouped with incorrect inclusions and names

```
settembre [settembre]
agosto [agosto]
febbraio [febbraio]
```

"`Corriere della Sera Sette 25 Agosto 2023`"  and also "`Il Messaggero`" are erroneously included in

```
settembre [settembre]
agosto [agosto]
```

but they must be considered as distinct elements. This picture show the wrong grouping:

[image]

I made my attempt with this code

**Function to group texts such as** `Il messaggero 21 settembre 2023` or `Le Grandi Glorie del Rock – 15 febbraio 2023`

```
function groupByDate(data) {
    var groupedData = {};
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        var date = item.id.match(/\d{1,2}\s(?:gennaio|febbraio|marzo|aprile|maggio|giugno|luglio|agosto|settembre|ottobre|novembre|dicembre)\s\d{4}/i);
        if (date) {
            date = date[0].toLowerCase();
            if (!groupedData[date]) {
                groupedData[date] = [];
            }
            groupedData[date].push(item);
        } else {
            if (!groupedData['other']) {
                groupedData['other'] = [];
            }
            groupedData['other'].push(item);
        }
    });
    return groupedData;
}
```

**Regex to make the match**

```
function extractGroup(text) {
    var containsNxM = /\d+x\d+/.test(text);
    var containsDate = /\d{1,2}\s(?:gennaio|febbraio|marzo|aprile|maggio|giugno|luglio|agosto|settembre|ottobre|novembre|dicembre)\s\d{4}/i.test(text);

    if (containsNxM) {
        var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+\s\d+x)/);
        return match ? match[0] : '';
    } else if (containsDate) {
        var match = text.match(/\d{1,2}\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s\d{4}/i);
        return match ? match[1] : '';
    } else {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Table initialization**

```
function initializeDataTable(data) {
    if (dataTable) {
        dataTable.destroy();
    }
    var tableData = [];
    if (grouped) {
        var groupedData = {};

        data.forEach(function(item) {
            var groupName = extractGroup(item.id);
            if (!groupedData[groupName]) {
                groupedData[groupName] = [];
            }
            groupedData[groupName].push(item);
        });

        // Inserisci un log per verificare groupedData
        console.log("groupedData:", groupedData);

        for (var groupName in groupedData) {
            if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) {
                var groupItems = groupedData[groupName];
                var badgeText = groupItems[0].badge;
                var badgeClass = 'badge-' + (badgeText || '').toLowerCase();
                var commonText = groupName.split('[')[0].trim(); // Estrai la parte comune dal nome
                tableData.push({
                    "checkbox": '<input type="checkbox" class="grouped-checkbox">',
                    "id": '<span class="badge ' + badgeClass + '">' + badgeText + '</span> ' + commonText + ' [' + groupName + ']', // Cambio qui
                    "username": groupItems.map(function(item) {
                        return item.username;
                    }).join('<br>'),
                    "extra": '<button class="downloadBtn">Scarica</button>',
                    "showLinks": groupItems.length > 2
                });
            }
        }
```

Complete code of table initialization is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/Nqee5Kyj) but I think that is useless for this purpose

Comment: Your grouping key should just be the month and year, but you're including the day number in your match.

Answer (score 1):

Your grouping key needs to keep the part of the text before the date, and remove the day number. Use a regexp replacement for this.

```js
function groupByDate(data) {
  var groupedData = {};
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var date = item.id.replace(/^(.*?)\d{1,2}\s((?:gennaio|febbraio|marzo|aprile|maggio|giugno|luglio|agosto|settembre|ottobre|novembre|dicembre)\s\d{4})/i, '$1[$2]');
    if (date != item.id) {
      key = date[0].toLowerCase();
    } else {
      key = 'other';
    }
    if (!groupedData[key]) {
      groupedData[key] = [];
    }
    groupedData[key].push(item);
  });
  return groupedData;
}
```

Comment: Nothing change, look [here](https://i.imgur.com/2HIxmAS.png) - you can test a live version of your code [HERE](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/) - click on `quotidiani` radio button and then press `Raggruppa` button to see rows grouped. Another error of your code is that it duplicates names for 'serietv', before in grouped mode it was only *Supercar 2x* text but with your code I get *Supercar 2x [Supercar 2x]*

Comment: Please use a [stack snippet] to put the live code here.

Comment: I used python & javascript and it is a server-side table version, I can't insert a simple stack snippet

Comment: My answer is just solving the first part of the question that says "and I'm trying to group them like this and with these names". I didn't read through the whole thing to see if there were multiple problems to solve.

Comment: Thank you, but there are no multiple problems, your solution doesn't actually solve my only problem which is the one you wrote to me, I just wanted to tell you that it presents the same problem again

Answer (score 1):

I solve in this way: I create 2 functions for each radio button / badge

```
function extractGroup(text) {
    var containsNxM = /\d+x\d+/.test(text);
    if (containsNxM) {
        var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+\s\d+x)/);
        return match ? match[0] : '';
    } else {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and this

```
function groupNewspapers(text) {
  var containsHash = /#\s\d+\s\w+\s\d+/g.test(text);
  if (containsHash) {
    var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/gm);
    return match.map(function(line) {
      return line.replace(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/, '$1 # $2').replace(/^\d+\s\w+\s/, '');
    }).join('\n');
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}
```

and for table initialization  I rewrite in this way

```
function initializeDataTable(data) {
    if (dataTable) {
        dataTable.destroy();
    }
    var tableData = [];
    if (grouped) {
        groupedData = {};
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            var groupName;
            if (item.badge === 'serietv') {
                groupName = extractGroup(item.id);
            } else if (item.badge === 'quotidiani') {
                groupName = groupNewspapers(item.id);
            }

            if (!groupedData[groupName]) {
                groupedData[groupName] = [];
            }
            groupedData[groupName].push(item);
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).